# Regex that accepts only numbers (0-9) and NO white spaces

Tags: regex, numbers

I need a regex that will accept only digits from 0-9 and no white spaces. Example:

35 62 30 36 63 63 61 63 39 65 34 66 64 33 34 62 66 66 61 63 34 38 39 38

And i want this:
356230366363616339653466643334626666616334383938

Is this possible? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use `^\d+$`.

Comment: Are you trying to do a replace? All languages with Regex allow you to replace the blanks with an empty string, without even using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely.

What you want is only select only digits with infinity amount

The digit is: `\d`
The multiplier which is not allow zero matches: `+`

So the solution is `\d+`. That is you want to apply on the string

---

Otherwise, if you want to apply the rule *do not match the whitespaces*, you need to go with a negated rule.

The easier solution is the character whitespace(`\s`) negated version: `\S`

So you can say `\S+`